# Does the Github action 'matrix' provide a complete list of runners with the specified tag or just grab the first runner with that tag?

Tags: github-actions

I would like to know if the Github action **matrix** will gather all the runners vms with a label say 'tag1' if there were multiple runners with the same label 'tag1' and not just grab the first one?  Thank you for the help!

```
  update-runners:
    needs: [env]
    runs-on: ["self-hosted", "${{ matrix.runner }}", "${{ needs.env.outputs.env }}"]
    strategy:
      matrix:
        runner: [ tag1, tag2, tag3 ]
```

Runner VMs:

- Machine-1 with label: tag1
- Machine-2 with label: tag1
- Machine-3 with label: tag2

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly (so feel free to tell me if I'm wrong), but you can run the job in parallel on different runners informing them in the strategy, in your case, using something like this implementation in you workflow `matrix: runner: ['windows-latest', 'ubuntu-latest', 'macos-latest']`. [Here is an example](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-pyinstaller/blob/main/.github/workflows/pyinstaller.yml). Note that you can use specific versions as well, instead of the latests (e.g: ubuntu-20.04).

Comment: @GuiFalourd, Yes - I wasn't clear.  If you have multiple vms with the same label, will the matrix return all the vms or just the first one vm with the label?  Fyi, I updated my question to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes - the matrix will gather all the vms that match and not just grab the first match.